# Statsmodels ARIMA, Value warning, date index and associated frequency information

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, statsmodels, arima

I am currently building ARIMA models in python and has come across this error which I dont really understand when looking through the error code. I am curious if it affects the parameters in the model and would really appreciate if someone could advice on the issue, probably suggest a fix.

A date index has been provided, but it has no associated frequency information and so will be ignored when e.g. forecasting.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNZjd.png

The code in the error documentation in github goes as:

```
date_index = isinstance(index, (DatetimeIndex, PeriodIndex))

    if date_index and not has_freq:
        warnings.warn('A date index has been provided, but it has no'
                      ' associated frequency information and so will be'
                      ' ignored when e.g. forecasting.', ValueWarning)
```

Here is my dataframe. I have the date time set as my dataframe index.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlkd0.png

Just to be clear, the code is still executable and the result summary can be printed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This warning shows up when your date index does not have a frequency associated with it.You have not provided a defined frequency (like quarterly, monthly, etc associated with the data/time index.

What this warning means is that you cannot specify forecasting steps by dates, and the output of the forecast and get_forecast methods will not have associated dates. The reason is that without a given frequency, there is no way to determine what date each forecast should be assigned to. Try specifying a period like below:

```
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index).to_period('M')
```

Read this page here for more details on the same.
https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/statespace_forecasting.html

Comment: Thanks for providing the page regarding the details. Following the steps in the page provided, I printed the index and it showed that it was lacking frequency. `df.index.to_timestamp()` seems to fix the issue, adding frequency into the index.